# Plotly Yaxis2 format tick labels in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to display anything other than straight zeros on my secondary Y-axis using `plotly` with the data given in the R Markdown code below:

````
---
title: "Test Stack Overflow Trending"
author: ""
date: ""
output:
   html_document:
      self_contained: no
---

```{r plot1, results='asis', tidy=FALSE, echo=FALSE, fig.retina=NULL, message=FALSE, out.width = "92%", out.height="450px"}

require(plotly)
require(data.table)

mydt <- data.table(NAME = "Overall", Val = c(391234, 518834, 489567),perc = c(0.24,0.25,0.24), mytdate=c("2015-09-01","2015-10-01","2015-11-01"))

mydt$mydate <- as.Date(mydt$mytdate,"%Y-%m-%d")

p1 <- mydt %>%
  plot_ly(x = mydate, y = Val,type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
add_trace(x = mydate, y = perc, yaxis = "y2", mode="lines+markers") %>%
  layout(showlegend = F, xaxis=list(title=""),yaxis=list(title=""),yaxis2 = list(side="right",overlay="y", ticks="inside",tickformat = ":04,2f"))

p1

```
````

I am using R 3.1.3 64-bit on a Windows 7 64-bit operating system.  I am using the plotly package version: 2.0.16 (downloaded from Github in mid December of 2015).

Here is the image I am getting using Google Chrome, version: 47.0.2526.111 attached below.  Notice that my right hand axis shows constant zeros.  I want it to display something like 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24.  I know there has to be a way to change this with the tickformat option, but I still have yet to figure it out.
[Output seen in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T9i0.png)

Comment: I just try https://plot.ly/r/multiple-axes/ and it worked for your example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had an idea how to fix your problem, but I needed to find it in the documentation. So you just need to play with the margin and the size of your plot. In addition, it will give you plenty of margin to add labels.

```
m = list(
    l = 50,
    r = 50,
    b = 100,
    t = 100,
    pad = 4
)
```

and add a `layout()` and just play with `height` and `width`

```
p1 <- mydt %>%
    plot_ly(x = mydate, y = Val,type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
    add_trace(x = mydate, y = perc, yaxis = "y2", mode="lines+markers") %>%
    layout(showlegend = F, xaxis=list(title=""),yaxis=list(title=""),yaxis2 = list(side="right",overlay="y", ticks="inside",tickformat = ":04,2f")) %>% layout(autosize = F, width = 750, height = 500, margin = m)

p1
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!

Comment: All I needed to do was add the "autosize=F, margin=m" in the layout() I already had in place.  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution to my own question.  If I remove the showlegend=F option in the layout, the y2 axis will display correctly.  I still cannot figure out how to get it to work if I don't want to display the legend.  Also, I have the wrong option in the layout, it should read "overlaying", not "overlay".  Still would appreciate a better answer with showlegend=F if possible.